# Openshift MySQL database contents resets at build

Tags: mysql, openshift, persistence.xml

I am using Openshift to build an EJB database using MySQL.
My application is working as expected.
However, when I rebuild it, the database contents is removed and the database starts from empty.

Here is my persistence unit from my persistence.xml

```html
  <persistence-unit name="production">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MySQLDS</jta-data-source>

    <class>net.applicationName.model.Customer</class>

      <properties>

          <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="MySQL"/>
          <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>

          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://url:port/jbossews" />
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user" />
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="pwd" />

         <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
```

Any advice

Patrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your create-drop to something else,

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
```

Basically you are telling your application to drop all tables, and recreate them.  You should look up other values for that option.

Comment: Also needed to change <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>